University Student Dataset
I need to find real-world student data including GPA, major/minor, year, skills, and areas of interest. Where can I find such a dataset?

Real-world student data that includes all of these details will be extremely challenging to find due to privacy concerns.
But you may want to check out some open datasets at NCES
or
UCI
